# How to change ConnectionString property of SqlDataSource by Code Behind which is in Child ReorderList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two `ReorderList` One is a parent and other is its child. I want to change dynamically the `ConnectionString` property of `SqlDataSource` through code behind but I am unable to change `ConnectionString` property of Child `ReorderList` even I tried `OnItemDataBound` and tried to find the control and change its property but could not. Here is a sample of code which I am using:

```
     <div class="reorderListDemo" style="width: 100%">
    <cc1:ReorderList ID="ReorderList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyField="RecordingFilterId" AllowReorder="true"
        SortOrderField="Priority" PostBackOnReorder="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table style="width: 100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="6%" style="padding-left:5px;padding-top:3px;">
                        <a href="javascript:switchViews('divRF<%# Eval("RecordingFilterId") %>', 'dragHandle<%# Eval("RecordingFilterId") %>');">
                            <img id="imgdivRF<%# Eval("RecordingFilterId") %>" border="0" src="Images/expand.png" />
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="34%">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' meta:resourcekey="Label7Resource1" /></td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6" width="100%" style="padding-right:10px;" >
                            <div id="divRF<%# Eval("RecordingFilterId") %>" style="display: none; width: 99%;">
                                <table style="width: 100%;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="color: white; width: 15%; padding-left: 30px;" class="topleft" align="left">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <b>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Rule" meta:resourcekey="Label3Resource2"></asp:Label></b>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                <div class="reorderListDemo" style="margin-left: 0px;width: 97%;">
                                    <cc1:ReorderList ID="ReorderList2" runat="server" PostBackOnReorder="False" CallbackCssStyle="callbackStyle"
                                        AllowReorder="True" DataKeyField="RuleId" SortOrderField="Priority"
                                        >
                                        <ItemTemplate>                                                                
                                                <table style="width: 100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="left" style="padding-left: 10px; width: 15%;">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Eval("RuleName") %>' Text='<%# Eval("RuleName").ToString().Length > 14 ? Eval("RuleName").ToString().Substring(0,12) + ".." : Eval("RuleName").ToString() %>' />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>                                                              
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ReorderTemplate>
                                            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="reorderCue" meta:resourcekey="Panel2Resource1">
                                            </asp:Panel>
                                        </ReorderTemplate>
                                        <DragHandleTemplate>
                                            <div class="dragHandleChild" id="dragHandle<%# Eval("RecordingFilterId") %>">
                                            </div>
                                        </DragHandleTemplate>

                                    </cc1:ReorderList>
                                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>"
                                        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
                                        OnDeleted="OnRuleDeleted" SelectCommand="SELECT RuleId,RecordingFilterId,RuleName,RecordingAction,RecordingCondition,ExtensionValue,Priority,CallType FROM rules  WHERE ([RecordingFilterId] =@RecordingFilterId)  and RuleName &lt;&gt; '' ORDER BY [Priority] asc"
                                        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Rules] SET [Priority] = @Priority WHERE RuleId = @original_RuleID"
                                        DeleteCommand="exec DeleteRule @original_RuleID" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
                                        <DeleteParameters>
                                            <asp:Parameter Name="original_RuleID" />
                                        </DeleteParameters>
                                        <SelectParameters>
                                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblCategoryName" Name="RecordingFilterId" PropertyName="Text"
                                                Type="String" />
                                        </SelectParameters>
                                        <UpdateParameters>
                                            <asp:Parameter Name="Priority" Type="Int32" />
                                            <asp:Parameter Name="original_RuleID" Type="String" />
                                        </UpdateParameters>
                                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

        </ItemTemplate>

        <ReorderTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="reorderCue" >
            </asp:Panel>
        </ReorderTemplate>
        <DragHandleTemplate>

            <div class="dragHandle" id="dragHandle<%# Eval("RecordingFilterId") %>">
            </div>
        </DragHandleTemplate>
    </cc1:ReorderList>

</div>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT RecordingFilterId,Name,Description,SystemFilter,Priority FROM recordingfilters WHERE SystemFilter='1' AND STATUS =1  order BY Priority"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [recordingfilters] SET [Priority] = @Priority WHERE RecordingFilterId = @original_RecordingFilterId"
    OnDeleted="OnFilterDeleted" DeleteCommand="exec DeleteRecordingFilter @original_RecordingFilterId"
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_RecordingFilterId" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Priority" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_RecordingFilterId" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I can change the `ConnectionString` of `SqlDataSource1` through code behind and its accessible but `SqlDataSource2` is not accessible. Anyone kindly give me a clue how to achieve this as I want to assign Connection String from code behind.

Comment: May I know how you're trying to change the Connection String ?

Comment: @Nitin Alapati at Page_Load I am doing SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = "MyNewString";

Comment: @Nitin Alapati but unable to access sqlDataSource2

Comment: Try for any errors in syntax . It has to be accessible from code behind. Nothing stopping it AFAIK from your code .. try rebuilding the solution

Comment: @Nitin Alapati its in the child reorder list and it has to be different for every parent record so it is not. I have tried many possibilities but wit no luck.

Comment: What is a "cc1:ReorderList" ? It isn't a standard component.

Comment: It is tag prefix for AjaxToolKit like so `<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>` @nlips

Comment: Could you tell more about the ItemDataBound event ? For instance, in this method, did'nt `SqlDataSource sds2 = (SqlDataSource)(e.Item.FindControl("SqlDataSource2"));` work ? And then, access to its properties, like `ConnectionString`

Comment: @Lucas Delobelle I already tried this but this also did not work

Comment: That's weird...do you get any error message ? Or your var just takes `null` ? Since this is a control of the ItemTemplate it should find it...!

Comment: Yes it finds an element and even changes its Connection String property but its not binding the data with Reorderlist2. @LucasDelobelle

Comment: Ok nice, so you change the DataSource of the `ReorderList2` ReorderList to this SqlDataSource and then you can call its `DataBind()` method ?

Comment: Ok let me try this nice clue @Lucas Delobelle

Comment: Its working fine with your clue. Thank you @Lucas Delobelle Please post your answer so that I could mark it right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ItemDataBound` method, you can access the SqlDataSource :

```
sds = (SqlDataSource)(e.Item.FindControl("SqlDataSource2"));
```

So you can change its `ConnectionString` attribute.

Then, find your ReorderList control using the same way (`e.Item.FindControl`), and set its `DataSource` attribute to `sds`.

```
myReorderList.DataSource = sds;
```

Last, don't forget to call the `DataBind()` method of your RedorderList.

```
myReorderList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 5):

Since your control uses the ASP.NET Expressions mechanism to retrieve the connection string from the config file

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx

you should be able to replace

```
 <%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>
```

with your own custom expression provider

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.expressionbuilder.aspx

http://haacked.com/archive/2006/11/29/Express_Yourself_With_Custom_Expression_Builders.aspx/

This way you could have total imperative control over what actual value is provided to the context where the value is retrieved

```
 <%$ CustomExpressionProvider:MyConnectionString %>
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it on Item Data bound event of First reorder list ? @Wiktor Zychla